# Strip first and last 10 bytes of Pointer Array ( Scatter Gather List ) of Buffer data

Tags: c

I need to perform a compression operation and would require to strip first and last 10 bytes of user data and then program the remaining user buffer data for compression. The Array/SGL can have multiple buffers and varying data lengths. For now it is safe to assume that overall user data size is greater than 1000 bytes.

I am able to get the logic and functioning right if there is single user buffer array. However, for multiple buffer array we may have to iterate over buffers and modify **data_addr and data_len** and overall **num_src** value before programming compression such that first 10 bytes and last 10 bytes are stripped, which is where I am stuck. Any suggestions/pointers to blogs/code help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Buffer data structure
typedef struct
{
  void *data_addr;
  int  data_len; 
}T_BUF_DATA;

//data_len is the length of the data pointed by data_addr;

*int strip_header_in_user_data ( T_BUF_DATA *src, int num_src )
{


    // Strip the first 10 byes

    // single source data
    if ( num_src == 1 )
    {
       src[0].buf_addr = src[0].buf_addr +10;      // increase the offset by 10
       src[0].buf_len = src[0].buf_len -10 - 10 ; // first 10 and last 10 bytes are subtracted
       program_compression ( src, num_src ); 
    }

      // Multiple source buffers
      for ( int i = 0; i < num_src; i++ )
      {
         // Any suggestions here
         program_compression ( ??, ?? );
       }

}*


void program_compression ( T_BUF_DATA *src, int num_src )
{
}
```

Comment: Time to get a pencil and a sheet of paper.

Comment: @user13000627 How is the pointer data_adr built?

Comment: data_addr() are dynamic  memory address of source data ( uncompressed data )  allocated by the user .  User can allocate multiple source data buffers of varying lengths before making a final function  call strip_header_in_user_data  ();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem (`bytes` bytes to strip):

```
typedef struct
{
  void *data_addr;
  size_t  data_len; 
}T_BUF_DATA;


void strip(T_BUF_DATA *buff, size_t bytes)
{
    unsigned char *data  = buff -> data_addr;
    memmove(buff -> data_addr, data + bytes, buff -> data_len - 2 * bytes);
    buff -> data_len -= 2 * bytes;
}
```

or to strip nelements of the size of nsize

```
void strip(T_BUF_DATA *buff, size_t nelem, size_t nsize)
{
    unsigned char *data  = buff -> data_addr;
    memmove(buff -> data_addr, data + nelem * nsize, buff -> data_len * nsize - 2 * nelem * nsize);
    buff -> data_len -= 2 * nelem;
}
```

## edit

if you problem is how to use it on the array of those structures:

```
void stripWholeArray(T_BUF_DATA *buff, size_t nbuffers, size_t nbytes)
{
    while(nbuffers--)
    {
        strip(buff++, nbytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no need to memmove() any data after stripping the first and last 10 bytes. Also, I don't think your referenced code will work on multiple buffer data with varying data lengths.

Comment: @user13000627 why do you think so? what prevents this code from working on multiple buffers?

Comment: if I understand correctly, buff->data_addr corresponds to a contiguous single buffer entry only.

Comment: but `buff` can be anything having different buffers. You understand it wrong

Comment: Sorry I cant still get your code, the function you provided strips every source buffer ( buff ) first and last 10 bytes. This is not what I am expecting. I would like to strip first 10 bytes and last 10 bytes in complete source buffer array .

Comment: @user13000627 I do not understand you.  Explain what is : `complete source buffer array`

Comment: What's the purpose of memmove() in your example ?

Comment: if buffers are malloc-ed and assigned to the data_addr member and you change it - it will be not possible to free it. So you can move the memory in this case or just change the pointer. But it is so basic  - you need to put some effort as well

Comment: Instead of memmove() , we can adjust the buffer data_addr, data_len in a way that first 10 and last bytes of data structures are stripped

Comment: Good point.. I like your point about free() .Thanks . But above example strips every data buffer first and last 10 bytes. What's the scenario when data len of one of the source buffers  is less than 10 bytes ?

Comment: @user13000627 it is your part of the job. I have my own work to do. I will not wite many hundreds lines programs for yuo. Error checking - add it.